# How to get all synonyms of a specific schema

Tags: sql-server, metadata

I am using SQL Server 2019 and create in schema load synonyms based on a linked server. I have searched on the internet to a way to fetch a list of the created synonyms and find this URL ( https://anyonconsulting.com/business_intelligence/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-synonyms-in-sql-server-instance/ )

and execute the below statement:

```
SELECT name AS synonym_name,
base_object_name AS synonym_definition,
COALESCE (PARSENAME (base_object_name, 4), @@servername) AS server_name,
COALESCE (PARSENAME (base_object_name, 3), DB_NAME (DB_ID ())) AS DB_name,
COALESCE (PARSENAME (base_object_name, 2), SCHEMA_NAME (SCHEMA_ID ())) AS schema_name,
PARSENAME (base_object_name, 1) AS table_name,
create_date,
modify_date
FROM sys.synonyms
```

[image]

After executing this statement I get an empty result. So my question is how to get a list of the created synonyms based on linked server(s)

**Solution**

Thanks to the latest reply I fix the problem to put the database and schema name after the from:

```
SELECT name AS synonym_name,
base_object_name AS synonym_definition,
COALESCE (PARSENAME (base_object_name, 4), @@servername) AS server_name,
COALESCE (PARSENAME (base_object_name, 3), DB_NAME (DB_ID ())) AS DB_name,
COALESCE (PARSENAME (base_object_name, 2), SCHEMA_NAME (SCHEMA_ID ())) AS schema_name,
PARSENAME (base_object_name, 1) AS table_name,
create_date,
modify_date
FROM DEV_100_Load.sys.synonyms
```

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are USEing the correct database?

Comment: If the above statement returns no rows, then no `SYNONYM`s exist in the database you are *currently* connected to. Either you haven't connected to the right database, or your haven't created the `SYNONYM`s you think you have.

Comment: Hi Larnu, i understand your reaction. But that is not the case. I created based on a database link synonyms in the schema "syn". But the strange thing is that the  schema is not visable in the all objects. I eddited the question with the synonyms

Comment: @Erikhoeven - in the interest of troubleshooting, can you fully qualify the DMV? That is, `FROM DEV_100_Load.sys.synonyms`. Does that change the results?

Comment: Thanks that works!  I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name AS synonym_name,
base_object_name AS synonym_definition,
COALESCE (PARSENAME (base_object_name, 4), @@servername) AS server_name,
COALESCE (PARSENAME (base_object_name, 3), DB_NAME (DB_ID ())) AS DB_name,
COALESCE (PARSENAME (base_object_name, 2), SCHEMA_NAME (SCHEMA_ID ())) AS schema_name,
PARSENAME (base_object_name, 1) AS table_name,
create_date,
modify_date
FROM DEV_100_Load.sys.synonyms
```